# how geo_distance query works under the hood in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to use `geo_distance` query with Elasticsearch.

I need information about how it works under the hood, and what is latency?

Answer (score 0):

[Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) is a highly scalable open-source full-text search and analytics engine. It allows you to store, search, and analyze big volumes of data quickly and in near real time.

A [`geo_distance` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) is a type of [geo query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-queries.html) that you can use with Elasticsearch when you are dealing with geographical data. It finds documents that include locations within a specified distance of a central point.

[image: https://www.joomlageek.com/images/blog/2019/Dec/geek-elasticsearch-geo-distance.jpg]
(Example from "[Geek ElasticSearch updated to specially supports Location-Based Applications](https://www.joomlageek.com/blog/98-geek-elasticsearch-updated-to-specially-supports-location-based-applications) ", from **Thanh Nguyen**)

The `geo_distance` query works in the following way:

1. **Indexing**: When you index a document in Elasticsearch, and that document contains a geo-point field (a field containing a latitude and longitude), Elasticsearch will convert that latitude and longitude into a [geohash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html#_geohash_3). A geohash is a string representation of a geographical area, which allows for efficient querying and sorting of geographical data.
2. **Querying**: When you issue a `geo_distance` query, Elasticsearch will calculate the geohash of the central point you have specified in your query. It will then search the index for documents that contain a geohash that falls within the specified distance of the central point's geohash.
3. **Distance Calculation**: The distance between the geohash of the central point and the geohash of each document's location is calculated using a method that you can specify in your query. You can choose between several methods: "arc" (default), "plane", and "sloppy_arc".

As for your question about latency, in the context of Elasticsearch and computing in general, [latency](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/search-latency-guide/) is the delay before a transfer of data begins following an instruction for its transfer. It is basically the time it takes for a query to be processed and the results to be returned.

The latency of a `geo_distance` query in Elasticsearch can be influenced by several factors:

1. **Index Size**: The larger the index, the more data Elasticsearch has to sift through to find matching documents, which can increase latency.
2. **Document Size**: If documents are large or complex, it can take longer to retrieve them.
3. **Hardware**: The speed and capabilities of the server hardware that Elasticsearch is running on can significantly impact latency.
4. **Network**: If Elasticsearch is distributed across multiple nodes, network latency can affect the overall latency of queries.
5. **Query Complexity**: More complex queries, such as those that involve multiple fields or combine multiple conditions, can take longer to process.

If you are experiencing high latency with your `geo_distance` queries, you might consider optimizing your index or your queries, upgrading your hardware, or investigating network issues.

---

From "[Efficient sorting of geo distances in Elasticsearch](https://bonsai.io/blog/efficient-sorting-of-geo-distances-in-elasticsearch), the default algorithm used for calculating geo_distance is the "sloppy_arc" algorithm. This algorithm is an approximation of the Haversine formula, which is used to calculate the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere. The sloppy_arc algorithm is both fast and over 99% accurate.

The time complexity of the [Haversine formula](https://community.esri.com/t5/coordinate-reference-systems-blog/distance-on-a-sphere-the-haversine-formula/ba-p/902128#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20haversine(%CE%B8),longitude%20of%20the%20two%20points.) is O(1) for a single pair of `(lon, lat)` points. However, when you perform a `geo_distance` query in Elasticsearch, the complexity depends on the number of documents being processed. If you have many documents, the time to compute `geo_distances` for all of them can become non-trivial.

To optimize the performance of `geo_distance` queries, you can reduce the number of documents being processed by using filters or bounding boxes. This will limit the scope of the search to a specific area, reducing the number of documents for which geo_distances need to be calculated.

So the time complexity of calculating geo_distance for a single pair of `(lon, lat)` points should be O(1), but the overall complexity of a `geo_distance` query in Elasticsearch depends on the number of documents being processed, and any optimizations applied to the query.

---

From just the source code, the complexity of the `geo_distance` query algorithm in Elasticsearch can be analyzed as follows:

1. [`GeoDistanceQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/13fb93511c23fe0d1a02de07644a0415253010c5/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/GeoDistanceQueryBuilder.java): The complexity of this class mainly comes from building the query. Since it involves setting parameters and constructing the query object, the complexity is generally O(1) for a single query.
2. [`GeoPoint`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/13fb93511c23fe0d1a02de07644a0415253010c5/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/geo/GeoPoint.java): This class represents a geographical point with latitude and longitude coordinates. The complexity of operations in this class is generally O(1) since it involves simple arithmetic operations and comparisons.
3. [`GeoDistance`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/74a594d9a6d04431f1fc3ef226ba39fdcca9b6be/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/geo/GeoDistance.java): This enumeration defines various distance calculation methods. The complexity of the distance calculation depends on the chosen method. For example, the `SLOPPY_ARC` method has a complexity of O(1) for a single pair of (lon, lat) points.
4. [`GeoUtils`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/13fb93511c23fe0d1a02de07644a0415253010c5/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/geo/GeoUtils.java): This utility class contains various methods for working with geographical data. The complexity of these methods varies depending on the specific operation, but most of them have a complexity of O(1) since they involve simple arithmetic operations and comparisons.

Considering these classes, the complexity of the `geo_distance` query algorithm in Elasticsearch is primarily determined by the number of documents being processed. For each document, the distance calculation has a complexity of O(1). Therefore, if you have N documents, the overall complexity of the algorithm would be O(N).

However, it is important to note that this analysis only considers the classes I listed and excludes the underlying Lucene library and Elasticsearch's distributed architecture, which can have a significant impact on the overall complexity and performance of `geo_distance` queries.

Comment: The lengthy answer, but the most important thing is missing – what is the complexity/algorithm of `geo_distance`, i.e. time complexity/algorithm to transform `(lon, lat)` pair to `geo_distance` and to compute a query?

Comment: @Talos I have edited the answer and included what I have found so far.